# Ruby ActiveRecord and sql tuple support

Tags: sql, ruby, rails-activerecord

Does ActiveRecord support tuples in the where clause, assuming the underlying database does?

The resulting where clause would look something like:

```
where (name, address) in (('John', '123 Main St'))
```

I tried:

```
Person.where({[:name, :address] => ['John', '123 Main St']})
```

and it didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

```
tupleArray = [['John', '123 Main St'],['Jane', '124 Main St']]
Person.where("(name, address) IN (#{(['(?)']*tupleArray.size).join(', ')})", *tupleArray)
```

Comment: This is a hack, and doesn't qualify as being "supported" by ActiveRecord. Also, the hack was already mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rubyonrails-core/RnKkEwbcNCk/3AJz9UOy_d4J)

Answer (score 2):

```
Person.where("(name, address) IN ((?))", ['John', '123 Main St'])
```

Comment: That works with one tuple, but not with multiple tuples. I tried `[['John', '123 Main St'], ['Jane', '456 Oak St']]` but AR converts each of the 2 nested arrays into YAML.