# How to query WHERE (ColA, ColB, ColC) IN ((a1, b1, c1), (a2, b2, c2), ...)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

How do I find multiple records by sets of multiple values in Rails4 / ActiveRecord? I'd like to achieve something like:

`SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE (A, B, C) IN ((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), ...)`

The following way suggested by nsave does **not** work entirely.

`User.where({ name: ["Alice", "Bob"], age: [20, 30, 40]})`

will result in

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE name IN ('Alice', 'Bob') AND age IN (20, 30, 40)`

What I need exactly is a piece of code that results in

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE (name, age) IN (('Alice', 20), ('Bob', 30))`

I'd like to do search for all rows that contain exactly one out of many sets of values. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Chain multiple `where` calls

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/31485318/846163

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now answering my own question as there seems to be no official way with problems like that when using ActiveRecord 4.2.4.

I solved my problem by extending AR with a new method especially made for querying tuples:

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    class << self

      # not really compatible to the rest of ActiveRecord but it works
      # provide parameters like this: symbols_tuple = [ :col1, :col2, :col3 ]
      # and values_tuples = [ [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
      # this will result in a SQL statement like SELECT * FROM table WHERE ((col1, col2, col3) IN ((1,4,7),(2,5,8),(3,6,9)))
      def where_tuple(symbols_tuple, values_tuples)
        tuple_size = symbols_tuple.size

        tuple_part = "(#{(['?']*tuple_size).join(',')})"
        in_stmt = "(#{([tuple_part]*values_tuples.size).join(', ')})"
        stmt = "(#{symbols_tuple.map { |sym| sym.to_s }.join(', ')}) IN #{in_stmt}"

        res = where(stmt, *(values_tuples.flatten!))

        return res
      end

    end # end of class << self
  end # end of class Base
end
```

This doesn't really integrate too well into the usual ways of ActiveRecord but at least for my cases it does the job.

Please let me know if you can think of a way on how to solve problems like this in a more elegant way!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly then simply:

```
User.where({ name: ["Alice", "Bob"], age: [20,30,40] })
```

Comment: Yes, this is it! After debugging through ActiveRecord all day I actually never thought of trying the obvious and simple way first. Of course, it's this simple in the end! Sorry for asking this question I could have answered myself!

Comment: @steschul, ok, you are welcome but please try to read docs more before asking such questions. And accept answers if they help you.

Comment: Sorry, I need to unmark this answer. After adding more tests I found out that this solution leads to wrong results under certain conditions. I'll update the question soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
Foo.where('bar = ? AND baz = ?', 1, 2)
```

This query searches for `Foo.bar` of `1` **and** `Foo.baz` of `2`

the query could go on, you can pass as many conditions as you need. You can also use other operators like `>` and `>=`. For example you can do `Foo.where('bar >= ?', 3)` querying `Foo` class for `bar` with more or equal to 3.